# How can we determine reference equality for strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to determine whether two strings point to the same location in memory? I know that for objects, ===, ==, and Object.is can be used for this purpose (see [MDN: Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)  and [MDN: Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)), but when used on strings, these will compare the *contents* of the strings, not their references...

Comment: There is no way to do this, it's not defined in the official EcmaScript spec. It's an implementation detail of the engine whether or not they want to point multiple references to the same location in memory.

Comment: That's what's kind of nice about immutable values: You don't really have to care whether a value is a "value-type" or "reference-type" value. It's indistinguishable.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript provides no API for determining any information about memory. It abstracts memory management.

Whether two variables containing identical strings are implemented under the hood as points to the same memory location or not is an implementation detail that you can't control or determine.